# Installing Sencha Command problems with osx and zsh

Tags: extjs, sencha-command

I can't get sencha command 3.0.0.250 to install correctly.

I'm on OSX 10.7.5. Using zsh shell.

Installing sencha command I install to the default "users/mark/bin"

I've downloaded sencha touch 2.1.0 commercial and navigated to that sdk folder. Running "sencha" in terminal gives "zsh: command not found: sencha"

I guess I'm installing to the wrong directory?

Advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone else is having this problem, the solution is to create an alias in your .zshrc file to the sencha executable. In my case this looked like this

```
alias sencha="~/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/sencha"
```

Comment: In my case was '/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/sencha'

Answer (score 2):

The command:

`alias sencha="~/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/sencha"`

Will work BUT... make sure that you match the number of the version that you installed. ie:

`alias sencha="~/bin/Sencha/Cmd/<version number installed>/sencha"`

Took me an hour to figure this out...

On the terminal, run:

1. `nano ~/.zshrc`
2. then add:

`alias sencha="~/bin/Sencha/Cmd/<VERSION NUMBER>/sencha"`

3. save the file and restart your terminal.

This should do the trick.